# Dependency Graph resolution problem with Neo4j-Swift (Theo)

Tags: swift, neo4j, vapor

I’m having trouble installing the Neo4j Theo SDK dependency into my Vapor 3 project (Swift 4.2). I have configured my Package.swift file like this:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.2
import PackageDescription
let package = Package(
...
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "3.3.1"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "3.2.1"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-postgresql.git", from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/auth.git", from: "2.0.4"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/console.git", from: "3.1.1"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor-community/pagination.git", from: "1.0.9"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Jinxiansen/Guardian.git", from: "3.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver-Vapor.git", from: "1.1.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver.git", .exact("1.6.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Neo4j-Swift/Neo4j-Swift.git", .exact("4.0.2")),
    ],
...
)
```

However when I try to fetch the Swift dependencies I receive this error:

```
Updating https://github.com/Neo4j-Swift/Neo4j-Swift.git
error: dependency graph is unresolvable; found these conflicting requirements:
Dependencies: 
    https://github.com/Neo4j-Swift/Neo4j-Swift.git @ 4.0.2
```

I wonder what I'm doing wrong here? I have also tried the latest version of Theo (Swift 5.0) and receive the same error. Any help on integrating the Theo package into a SPM project would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is that the full error? If you do `swift build --enable-pubgrub-resolver` you usually get better error messages about what the conflicting dependencies are